# Nth Business Week of the month

Tags: r

Is is possible to get the Nth business week of the month? Currently I have the following code but it takes in to account weekends. So for example if we give the date `2016-10-10`, this will give `3` as currently week of month. In reality, this is actually the 2nd business week of month.

```
wk <- function(x) as.numeric(format(x, "%U")); 
cur.wom = wk(d) - wk(as.Date(cut(d, "month"))) + 1
```

Comment: You might want to define "business week" more explicitly so we know exactly what you mean.

Comment: weekdays....no weekends

Comment: So is 5 working days a business week? Or does every Monday signal a new business week regardless of days?

Comment: So this month, we have 5 business weeks even though the first and last week of this month is not a full 5 days. But last month, we had 4 business weeks. October 2016 had 4 business weeks because Monday fell on the 3rd of October.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't tell from your question how you want weekends handled so the following code should work for Monday through Friday, but weekends may not go as you want.  The first thing you should do is convert the value to a `POSXlt` object as these have information about things like day of week built in.

```
myDate <- as.POSIXlt("2016-10-10", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

You may have to modify the `format` string for the date since it is ambiguous from your example if the format is year-month-day or year-day-month.

We can then use the following equation to get your business week value.

```
(myDate$mday - myDate$wday + 4) %/% 7 + 1
```

The `mday` field contains the day of the month for the date and `wday` contains a numerical value indicating the day of the week (starting at `0` on Sunday).  By subtracting `wday` from `mday` we get the same number for any day within the same week.  The `%/% 7` does integer division which will split things up into weeks.  The `+ 4` adjusts the value for each week so that when the `%/% 7` is applied it will indicate the week you want, no matter what day of the week the month starts on.  The final `+ 1` just converts the data so the coundint of weeks starts at `1` rather than `0`.